# FTP connection problems in Nautilus - seems to time out after a while

Tags: server, nautilus, ftp

I have no trouble connecting to my FTP server by going to **Places > Connect to server...**

I can then browse the FTP site to my heart's content with Nautilus for a few minutes.

After a few minutes of inactivity, if I try to bring up a folder on the site, Nautilus just displays a blank page.

The only remedy is to unmount the FTP site and reconnect.

This is quite annoying - is there some timeout issue at play here? Is there some way that I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: I experience this too, and it is one of the most annoying bugs in ubuntu. You can use the refresh button a few times in nautilus instead of remounting.

Comment: and @Nico: Have you tried my solution? Did it fix  the problem?

Comment: @qbi: It only works some of the time. Sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't. It's random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably extend the timeout in your system. Open the gconf-editor using `sudo gconf-editor` and navigate to `desktop -> gnome -> session`. There you find a key `idle_delay`. You can change that value by double-clicking on it. Depending from how long you are typically inactive you change it. So if you usually don't have FTP activity for half an hour set it to a value larger than 30.

There is also an entry in [Ubuntus bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/410288) and in [GNOME bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591054). GNOME seems to work on a fix.

Comment: this not work in ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

Probably not preventable easily on your end, and a timeout issue is the most likely cause.

That's a bug against `gvfs`, which would have to be modified to automatically handle such a situation. In the interim, I'd just remount as you've been doing.

You can report a bug against `gvfs` [on Launchpad](https://edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+filebug).

Comment: Ya... even if it just sent the NOOP FTP command every 2 minutes, that would be great.