# How to extend the timout in SFTP connections with Nautilus?

Tags: server, nautilus, ftp, sftp

I connect to a remote server using Nautilus (No, I don't like FileZilla). But after a bit of an idle moment, like 5 minutes it does not allows me to access again the remote location.

Even If I do get it sorted just mounting the server again, it's very annoying, as you can imagine, because I need to do that every 5 minutes.

I've read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463/ftp-connection-problems-in-nautilus) a similar issue, but it's an old post and it does not provides a working solution for Ubuntu Focal Fossa.

I've read [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19958/how-can-i-change-the-timeout-duration-for-nautilus-find-the-filename-as-you-t) as well, but I'm not sure the answer applies to my problem.

Finally, I've read [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/377322) where there seems to be a problem, but not any solution or workaround yet?

There seems to be a suggested [workaround here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=246315#p246315), but I'm not sure how to do that either, or if it applies to this issue (I assumed that given than Mint and Ubuntu are Debian based systems, a Mint solution could work for Ubuntu?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something your client (Nautilus) can change. Instead, the server you are connecting to is closing the connection after a certain period of "inactive" connection time.

If you own the server and can make settings there, try editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and setting the following values:

```
ClientAliveInterval 1200
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

`ClientAliveInterval` sets the time in seconds after which the server checks if the client is still connected. `ClientAliveCountMax` sets how often it does that before it closes the connection.

So for a timeout of 1 hour, you need:
1 hour = 60 minutes = 3600 seconds, so `3` times `1200` seconds (the values above).

Also, see [this article](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-ssh-connection-timeout/) for further information on these settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help bkis! Could it be a security issue changing the alive interval to a couple of hours? Again, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well, yes. The reason the server closes the connection certainly is a security measure. But it will still do that, just later. The short default timeout is just a, well default. Because why should it wait longer if it's not needed? :)

Comment: Very kind. I've managed to change it to one hour with your help :) Thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome!